# Solving a system of linear PDEs using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I have the following system of PDEs:

Where: phi(d,e,f,g,h,j,k)

and c1-c8 are real valued constants
[image]

I coded it into mathematica like this:

```
eqns = {C1*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], g] - 
    C2*f*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], k] + 
    C1*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], f] - 
    C3*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], d] == 0,
      C1*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], h] - 
    C2*g*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], k] + 
    C4*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], j] - 
    C3*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], e] == 0,
      C5*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], d] - 
    C2*h*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], k] - 
    C6*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], g] - 
    C6*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], f] == 0,
      C5*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], e] - 
    C2*j*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], k] - 
    C7*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], j] + 
    C8*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], j] - 
    C6*k*D[phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], h] == 0}
```

And called Dsolve:

```
Dsolve[eqns, phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k]]
```

Unfortunately Dsolve is not able to solve it.

I formulated these PDEs from an engineering problem and to the best of my knowledge it should have atleast 4 solutions to it.

I want to know if this is beyond mathematica's ability to solve or if I did some preprocesssing of some kind if it would help?

I am just starting to learn about PDEs so I'm not quite sure what I could do from my end to help Mathematica solve it.

Comment: Check your spelling: It should be `DSolve` rather than `Dsolve`. Even with the correct spelling, it does not return a result. Are you sure that *analytical* solutions exist? Could you say more about where the equations come from?

Comment: You have 4 equations, but 7 variables. You can't get a solution of underdetermined equation. Futher look up, how to use DSolve correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DSolve` has difficulty solving systems of first-order linear PDEs, for instance, [163482](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163482/1063) or [174971](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174971/1063).  Here, too it can obtain a solution, but not without assistance.  Begin by solving the first of the four equations.

```
s1 = DSolveValue[eqns[[1]], phi[d, e, f, g, h, j, k], {d, e, f, g, h, j, k}] /. 
    C[1][z1__][z2__] -> xi1[z1, z2]
(* xi1[e, h, j, (C1 d + C3 f)/C3, (C1 d + C3 g)/C3, 
   (-C1 C2 d^2 - 2 C2 C3 d f + C3^2 k^2)/(2 C3^2)] *)
```

Then insert this result into the fourth equation.

```
Simplify[#/k & /@ (eqns[[4]] /. phi -> Function[{d, e, f, g, h, j, k}, Evaluate@s1])]
(* C2*j*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1][xi1][e, h, j, (C1*d)/C3 + f, (C1*d)/C3 + g, 
   -(C1*C2*d^2 + 2*C2*C3*d*f - C3^2*k^2)/(2*C3^2)] + ... *)
```

(The whole expression is a bit long to reproduce here.)  Now, `DSolve` does not like independent variable like `(C1*d)/C3 + f`, so they must be replaced by dummy variables.

```
var = Array[Unique["v"] &, 6];
rls = Simplify[Thread[List @@ s1 -> var]]
(* {e -> v11, h -> v12, j -> v13, (C1 d)/C3 + f -> v14, (C1 d)/C3 + g -> v15, 
   -((C1 C2 d^2 + 2 C2 C3 d f - C3^2 k^2)/(2 C3^2)) -> v16} *)

s4 = Simplify[DSolveValue[%%% /. rls, xi1 @@ var, var] /. 
    C[1][z1__][z2__] -> xi4[z1, z2] /. (Reverse[#] & /@ rls)]

(* xi4[(C1 d)/C3 + f, (C1 d)/C3 + g, (C6 e)/C5 + h, (C7 e - C8 e + C5 j)/C5, 
   1/2 (-((C1 C2 d^2)/C3^2) - (2 C2 d f)/C3 + (C2 e (C7 e - C8 e + 2 C5 j))/C5^2
   + k^2)] *)
```

Substituting this result into the third equation then gives

```
Simplify[#/k & /@ (eqns[[3]] /. phi -> Function[{d, e, f, g, h, j, k}, Evaluate@s4])]
(* (C2*(C1*C5*d + C3*(-(C6*d) + C5*f + C3*h))*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 1][xi4]
   [(C1*d)/C3 + f, (C1*d)/C3 + g, (C6*e)/C5 + h, (C7*e - C8*e + C5*j)/C5, 
   (-((C1*C2*d^2)/C3^2) - (2*C2*d*f)/C3 + (C2*e*(C7*e - C8*e + 2*C5*j))/C5^2
   + k^2)/2])/C3 + ... *)
```

To proceed, the coefficient `(C2*(C1*C5*d + C3*(-(C6*d) + C5*f + C3*h))` must be expressed in terms of the six compound arguments of `xi4` or eliminated some other way.  In fact, it is easy to see that the coefficient cannot be expressed in terms of the six arguments, so instead the derivative must be set equal to zero.  This is accomplished mechanically by

```
% /. Derivative[n__, 1][xi4][z__, _] -> 0 /. 
    Derivative[n__, 0][xi4][z__, _] -> Derivative[n][xi4][z]
(* (-(C1*C5) + C3*C6)*(Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][xi4][(C1*d)/C3 + f, (C1*d)/C3 + g, 
   (C6*e)/C5 + h, (C7*e - C8*e + C5*j)/C5] + Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][xi4]
   [(C1*d)/C3 + f, (C1*d)/C3 + g, (C6*e)/C5 + h, (C7*e - C8*e + C5*j)/C5]) == 0 *)
```

Now, solve as with the earlier intermediate results.

```
var = Array[Unique["v"] &, 4];
rls = Simplify[Thread[Most[List @@ s4] -> var]];
s3 = Simplify[DSolveValue[%%% /. rls, xi4 @@ var, var] /. 
    C[1][z1__][z2__] -> xi3[z1, z2] /. (Reverse[#] & /@ rls)]
(* xi3[(C6 e)/C5 + h, (C7 e - C8 e + C5 j)/C5, -f + g] *)
```

Finally, insert this into the remaining equation and solve.

```
Simplify[eqns[[2]] /. phi -> Function[{d, e, f, g, h, j, k}, Evaluate@s3]];
var = Array[Unique["v"] &, 3];
rls = Simplify[Thread[List @@ s3 -> var]]
s2 = Simplify[DSolveValue[%%% /. rls, xi3 @@ var, var] /. 
    C[1][z1__][z2__] -> xi2[z1, z2] /. (Reverse[#] & /@ rls)]
(* xi2[-f + g, -((C4 C6 e - C1 C7 e + C1 C8 e + C4 C5 h - C3 C7 h + C3 C8 h - 
   C1 C5 j + C3 C6 j)/(C1 C5 - C3 C6))] *)
```

which is the desired solution.  `phi` is an arbitrary function of the two remaining compound variables.  To verify this result, substitute it into `eqns`.

```
Simplify[eqns /. phi -> Function[{d, e, f, g, h, j, k}, Evaluate@s2]]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey for that detailed explanation.
I do have one more question though.

Are `(-f + g)` and `-((C4 C6 e - C1 C7 e + C1 C8 e + C4 C5 h - C3 C7 h + C3 C8 h - 
   C1 C5 j + C3 C6 j)/(C1 C5 - C3 C6))` the only solutions to this system (Aside from linear multiples of these)?

Does this approach ensure that all possible solutions to the system are found?

Comment: The solution is an arbitrary function of `-f + g` and `-((C4 C6 e - C1 C7 e + C1 C8 e + C4 C5 h - C3 C7 h + C3 C8 h - C1 C5 j + C3 C6 j)/(C1 C5 - C3 C6))`  Thus, there is a two dimensional space of solutions.  This is not surprising, because the problem has more independent variables than equations.  I am confident that there are no solutions outside this space.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer to question 32843](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32863/1063) provides an interesting alternative approach for solving the question here.  Beginning with the left sides of the equations in the question,

```
eqn = First /@ eqns;
```

recast the expressions into an equivalent form that can be integrated readily.

```
eqn2 = Union[eqn, Flatten[D[eqn, #] & /@ {d, e, f, g, h, j, k}]] // Simplify;
vars = Select[Variables[eqn2], ! FreeQ[#, phi] &];
elim = Cases[vars, Derivative[z__][_][__] /; Total[{z}] > 1];
keep = Complement[vars, elim];
gb = GroebnerBasis[Flatten@eqn2, keep, elim, CoefficientDomain -> 
    RationalFunctions, MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]

(* {Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k] + 
      Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k], 
    (-(C4*C6) + C1*C7 - C1*C8)*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k] + 
      (C4*C5 - C3*C7 + C3*C8)*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k], 
    (C4*C6 - C1*C7 + C1*C8)*Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k] + 
      (C1*C5 - C3*C6)*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k], 
    Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1][phi][d, e, f, g, h, j, k]} *)
```

By inspection, `phy` must be an arbitrary function of `g - f` (from `gb[[2]]`) and of some linear combination of `e, g, h` (from `gb[[3;;4]]`), and independent of `d` (from `gb[[1]]`) and `k` (from `gb[[5]]`).  The linear combination can be determined by

```
Coefficient[gb /. phi -> 
Function[{d, e, f, g, h, j, k}, x4[ae e + ah h + aj j, g - f]], 
    Derivative[1, 0][x4][ae*e + ah*h + aj*j, -f + g]
Flatten@Solve[Thread[% == 0], {ae, ah, aj}]

(* {ah -> -((ae (-C4 C5 + C3 C7 - C3 C8))/(C4 C6 - C1 C7 + C1 C8)), 
    aj -> -((ae (-C1 C5 + C3 C6))/(-C4 C6 + C1 C7 - C1 C8))} *)
```

This is equivalent to my earlier answer, obtained with greater effort.

If desired, this answer also can be obtained by systematically solving the five PDEs embodied by `gb`.  First solve `gb[[1;;5;;4]]`.

```
gb1 = DeleteCases[gb /. (Flatten@DSolve[Thread[Drop[gb, {2, 4}] == 0], 
    phi, {d, e, f, g, h, j, k}] /. C[1] -> x1), 0];
```

Next, solve `gb1[[1]]`, equivalent to `gb[[2]]`.

```
gb2 = DeleteCases[gb1 /. (Flatten@DSolve[First@gb1 == 0, x1, {e, f, g, h, j}] 
    /. C[1][z1__][z2_] -> x2[z1, z2]), 0]

(* {(-(C4*C6) + C1*C7 - C1*C8)*Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][x2][e, h, j, -f + g] + 
      (C4*C5 - C3*C7 + C3*C8)*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][x2][e, h, j, -f + g], 
    (C4*C6 - C1*C7 + C1*C8)*Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0][x2][e, h, j, -f + g] + 
      (C1*C5 - C3*C6)*Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][x2][e, h, j, -f + g]} *)
```

and solve these remaining two coupled PDEs in three variables by the method employed in my earlier answer or the method employed earlier in this answer.  Incidentally, `ae*e + ah*h + aj*j` and `-f + g` can be viewed as characteristics of the original PDEs.